# Example of rings with idempotent and non-zero Jacobson radical

Tags: ring-theory

I am looking for a simple (as simple as possible) example of a commutative ring (with identity) $R$ such that its Jacobson radical is non-zero but idempotent. (The simplest example that I know is $\Bbb{C}[[x, x^{\frac 12},x^{\frac 13},\cdots]]$ )

Comment: What do you mean when you say idempotent radical?

Comment: @Ivan $J(R)^2 = J(R)$ where $J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical of $R$, i.e., the intersection of all maximal ideals of $R$.

Comment: The simplest examples are all fields.

Comment: @Ivan I am afriad not ! The jacobson radical of a field is zero !

Comment: I'm sorry, I missread "non-zero."

Comment: @mathematics2x2life Dear editor, at least read what you are editing ! the character you have deleted is necessary !!

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathbf{C}_p$ denote the completion of an algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}_p$. This is a complete non-Archimedean field with non-discrete valuation, and its valuation ring $\mathscr{O}_{\mathbf{C}_p}$ is a local ring, not a field, with unique maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ satisfying $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{m}^2$.

Comment: Thanks. But I was looking for something simpler than $\Bbb{C}[[x, x^{\frac 12},x^{\frac 13},\cdots]]$ !

Comment: I didn't have to take the completion. An algebraic closure of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ has the same property. Note that your example is also the valuation ring of an algebraic closure of a discretely valued field (namely $\mathbf{C}((x))$).

Answer (score 2):

What you've given is just about the simplest example.  Along the same lines, one could try $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{1/2},\ldots]_{(x,x^{1/2},\ldots)}$ or $\mathbb{C}[x,x^{1/2},\ldots]/(x)$.

I think that anything simpler than this is very unlikely.  Nakayama's Lemma rules out any finitely generated algebra, so either we use infinitely many generators as above, or we find some ring with a rich structure that isn't easy to describe with generators (e.g. $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{C}_p}$).